# Tasks are removed from TFS Release Definition

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-extensions

We are TFS 2017 Update 3. This issue started to appear after upgrading from TFS 2017 update 1.

And we have a lot of custom TFS Tasks developed by us.

At times when a user opens a release definition or a release of the definition, the user gets prompted that 'Tasks not found' like below.

[image]

Let's assume the user clicks OK.

Then there is this dangerous option to 'Save' it. Saving it removes the tasks and it is quite not that easy to revert the definition with the history.

I am more interested to know why this prompt appears.

Comment: I haven't encountered this exact scenario before. I've seen some weird things happening when the PublisherId of an extension changes. I pinged the VSTS team to see if they have a clue or if they can help you.

Comment: I have not changed the PublisherID for sure.. but most of these tasks were developed when it was TFS Update 1.. and the issue is there only after the upgrade..

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you first go through the history of your release definition, if there   have unexpected edits. If something is causing a change to the definition, it should show there as an update and might provide some clues as to why these tasks disappearing.

Then also check if these custom tasks are also missing in the task list and corresponding build definition.

One possibility, if your custom task  is calling the TFS API where you have to specify the api-version parameter. You maybe still using the wrong version value. Updating API version on the TFS installation is only done when you upgrade the TFS version/update. When you are on TFS 2017 Update 1 so that specific version of the API may not be available in TFS 2017 Update 3.

For example if your task is using an old version of the REST api. For compatibility, elements of definitions that are not supported by a rest client's version are removed before sending the definition to the client. This unfortunately means that if the client then saves the definition the aspects that were not supported by its api version are removed from the definition.

You could also create a test new release definition then add same tasks as the old release definition to see if the issue still exists. This will narrow down the issue is related to task itself, or just some cache. For cache issue, please refresh it as *Pranay* suggested.

Comment: None of my tasks call any TFS API.. rather they all manage different tools like sqlcmd, splpackage, files.. the issue is intermittent and of course a refresh resolves it.. but if only everyone refreshes it would be fine.. but accidentally if any saves it then it is a nightmare.. as release apis are still I preview..

Comment: Your answer is taking me to the right direction.. it seems i am using an api version while uploading the tasks to TFS.. got to change this and see..

Comment: @BaskarLingamRamachandran Any update on this issue, sir?

Comment: This would take some time.. I need to check if this resurfaces with all stakeholders.. i will wait for a while before closing this..

Answer (score 0):

This should be an intermittent issue, refresh should fix it. If you are still facing the problem, you can upgrade your TFS to [TFS 2018](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2018-update1), in which this issue is fixed.